# Binary tree with Null pointer structure error

Tags: c

I am constructing a binary tree from a in order and post order list. The program generate the binary tree correctly from the TreeNode structure. I am trying to connect it to the Tree node structure and print out. See code. I am not sure how to connect Tree to Treenode??

The function buildutil is called from buildtree returns the correct binary tree but at the TreeNode structure. I want to return the return the binary tree from the Tree structure and trying to connect temproot now to trtemp from the Tree structure.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct trnode 
{
    TreeNode * root;
} Tree;

  // buildtree function calls helper function buildUtil which is 
 recursive
Tree * buildTree(int * in, int * post, int size)
{

int preindex = size - 1;
Tree * trtemp = NULL;
// correctly returns the biary tree in TreeNode structure
TreeNode * temproot = buildUtil(in, post, 0, preindex, &preindex); 

*trtemp -> root = *temproot;

// Print function to print out tree. Works correctly, printing  temproot from TreeNode strucuture
preOrder(trtemp);

}
```

Comment: Your title says "error". But what is the error? Your text describes what you have and what you want. But what is the question? Please edit your question and clarify what exactly you need help with. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. When I try to run the program. I get "trtemp was nullptr", when I try to set the trtemp ->root to point to the temproot. I want to somehow connect to Tree structure to Tree Node and return trtemp.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but please don't do that in comments. Edit your question instead. Thanks!

Comment: `trtemp` is `NULL` (you initialized it as such), so what do you expect `trtemp->root` to do?